# How to ensure single record being inserted in rails

Tags: ruby, postgresql, concurrency, ruby-on-rails-5

In our application, A user can be entered only once or multiple times to a campaign based on the configuration(single time or multiple times).

A user model, campaigns and campaigns_users model are there. If the configuration is single time, the campaigns_users should have only one record for a user. and if the campaign is configured with multiple times, there can be many records for the same user for the same campaign.

Due to concurrent processing, the record is being inserted twice. We have done the application level check to ensure whether the user entered into the campaign or not. In some cases, two processes run at the same time and check for the subscription to the campaign and the user got subscribed twice even if the configuration given as single time.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
    def already_subscribed?(campaign)
      campaign.campaigns_users.find_by(user_id: id).present?
    end
end
```

In job

```
def perform(user_id, campaign_id)
  campaign = Campaign.find_by(id:  campaign_id)
  user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
  return if campaign.config == 'single' && user.already_subscribed?

  # Other Logics
end
```

I have checked for the solution for avoiding the two entries for specific cases and the result I got is to add the **UNIQUE constraint**. But in my case, the user can be entered multiple times/single time based on the config. What can be the best solution for avoiding the creation of the record?

Comment: You might be able to apply an additional [conditional constraint](http://postgresguide.com/performance/conditional.html), assuming your configuration is also stored in the database

Comment: Okay, But that configuration also be changed right @JayDorsey? and also the configuration is in the campaign model.

Comment: you could do conditional validation

Comment: You mean in the application level @olucube.com?, If so I have already done that and due to the concurrent processes the validation is failed to work.

Comment: @Rthi yes. can you show your models' codes please?

Comment: I have edited in the post. Please check

Comment: Looking back at this, it looks like postgres can't do conditional constraints with joins on other tables, so you wouldn't be able to do what I was thinking initially. You'd have to store the configuration setting on the table to set the constraint, but then you'd have to deal with configuration changes (which you'd probably have to deal with anyways--what happens when someone has multiples then changes configs?) This might be a problem that a postgres trigger can solve, but either way I'd try an do this at the database layer

Comment: Thanks for the reply and what I am looking now is whether advisory locks can help in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using **Advisory lock** of Postgres(https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-postgresql-advisory-locks-work/). Please have a look over https://github.com/ClosureTree/with_advisory_lock gem

```
def perform(user_id, campaign_id)
  campaign = Campaign.find_by(id: campaign_id)
  user = User.find_by(id: user_id)

  # I have used id's as lock name to ensure reducing the time that other threads waiting for accessing this critical section
  CampaignUser.with_advisory_lock("#{user.id}-#{campaign.id}")
    return if campaign.config == 'single' && user.already_subscribed?

    # Other Logics
  end
end
```